# How to create session for current user

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

On the first visit i want to pass this rule on a page

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    // redirect them to your desired location
    header('location:404.php');
    exit;
}
```

after passing this rule how we can create a session for current visitor?

Comment: Your issue is understood from your code itself, First time the session value is not set  so it will set and redirects to 404.

Comment: It's also not a good idea to trust the `HTTP_REFERER`-header since not all clients will set it, for privacy reasons.

Comment: @Bilal Can you explain your requirement in detail: What I understood is on first loading check for session and it will set the session value and redirect to 404. On next loading the session is already set before(ie on first load) so we wont enter that condition and will not redirect. Will load with the remaining code

Comment: @Bilal So on first load what you need ?